# Chrome in Xmonad - Mouse Unresponsive

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, mouse, xmonad

I have Xmonad installed on Ubuntu 10.10.

When using google Chrome, sometimes the mouse becomes unresponsive (only inside chrome). The problem goes like this:

- I have several tabs open
- Click with the mouse to switch tabs
- The focus get stuck in the tabs, mouse wheel scrolls through the tabs, but not the page. Clicking on the page doesn't work. Clicking on other tabs doesn't work.

The workaround is to switch desktops. Switching back and forth (say from desktop 1 to 2 and back) makes the mouse responsive again, until I use the mouse to switch tabs, when the problem appears again.

Is this a problem with Chrome, Xmonad, or Ubuntu? Other applications are not affected... I've also had problems with Ubuntu's accessibility options (particularly mouse being operated by the numpad) turning on at random times, probably with a shortcut being used by Xmonad.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. The problem is not critical, but it's very annoying having to switch between desktops just to use the browser.

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 12 LTS. I don't know if I have Xmonad installed, but it's exactly the same problem.